# Проблема с циклами

Tags: c++

По моей задумке персонажи меняют своё положение на 1 клетку в одно случайное направление из восьми.
Проблема заключается в том, что за цикл они могут изменить своё положение на более, чем 1 клетка, а при добавлении обнуления переменных moveX и moveY программа вовсе начала крашиться.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
using namespace std;

static const int width = 1000;            //длина и ширина карты
static const int length = 1000;
int playField[width][length];             //массив карты
int moveX, moveY;                         //переменные новых координат

class Characters{
private:
    int id;
    int hp;                               //хапэшки
public:
    int area;
    int posX, posY;                       //позиция персонажа

    void moveTo(int newX, int newY, int ID){
            area = playField[moveX][moveY];     //сохр. значения клетки

            posX = newX;
            posY = newY;

            playField[newX][newY]=ID;
    }

    void setId(int newID){
        id = newID;
    }

    void showId(){
        cout<<"ID: "<<id<<endl;
    }

    void showPosition(){
        cout<<"X: "<<posX<<endl<<"Y: "<<posY<<endl;
    }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class PlayField{
private:
    int area;
public:
    void fillMap(){                         //тест функция
        for (int i=0; i<=width-1; i++)     //вбиваем нули в массив
        for (int j=0; j<=length-1; j++)
            playField[i][j]=-1;
    }

    void moveToFile(){
        ofstream file;
        file.open("C:\\Users\\NoName\\Desktop\\Game\\PlayField.txt",ios::out);

        cout<<"file status: "<<file.is_open()<<endl;      //проверка файла

        for (int i=0; i<=width-1; i++){                   //перенос массива в файл
            file<<endl;
        for (int j=0; j<=length-1; j++)
            file<<playField[i][j];
        }

        file.close();
    }

    void moveCh(int x, int y, int id){
        //playField[x][y]=id;
    }


};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(){
    cout<<"Welcome, nine tailed fox. Please input number of characters: ";
    bool cycleRunning = 1;                          //выключатель для основного цикла
    bool busy = 0;                                  //проверка свободности клетки
    int chX, chY;                                   //координаты спавна
    int way;                                        //направление сл. шага
    int seconds = 0;                                //для таймера
    srand(time(NULL));                              //объявление рандомайзера
    int numOfChar;
    cin>>numOfChar;                                  //кол-во чаров

    int *charId = new int[numOfChar];                //массив ид
    int lastID = 0;                                  //посл ид

    PlayField field;

    field.fillMap();

    Characters *ch = new Characters[numOfChar];         //создание персонажей
    for(int i=0; i<numOfChar; i++){
        busy = 0;
        ch[i].setId(i);

        do{
        chX = rand()%1000, chY = rand()%1000;           //начальные координаты

        if (i<2)
            if (i==1)
                if(ch[0].posX==chX)
                if(ch[0].posY==chY)
                busy = 1;

        else
            for(int j=i-2; j>=0; j--){
                if(ch[j].posX==chX)                     //проверка наличия предыдущих чаров на клетке
                if(ch[j].posY==chY)
                busy = 1;
            }
        }while(busy == 1);

        ch[i].moveTo(chX, chY, i);
        ch[i].showPosition();
        ch[i].showId();
        cout<<endl;
    }

    while(cycleRunning != 0){
        if(kbhit()==1)
            cycleRunning=0;

        if(seconds != time(NULL)){                  //таймер
            seconds = time(NULL);

            for(int i=0; i<numOfChar; i++){
                do{
                busy = 0;

                    if (i<2)
                    switch (i){
                        case 0: {
                            way = rand() % 8;
                            switch (way)                       //выбор направления и перемещение
                            {
                                case 0: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 1: {moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 2: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 3: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1;} break;
                                case 4: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 5: {moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 6: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 7: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1;} break;
                            }

                            if(moveX<0)
                            if(moveY<0)
                            busy = 1;
                        } break;

                        case 1: {
                            way = rand() % 8;
                            switch (way)
                            {
                                case 0: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 1: {moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 2: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                                case 3: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1;} break;
                                case 4: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 5: {moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 6: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                                case 7: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1;} break;
                            }

                            if(moveX<0)
                            if(moveY<0)
                            if(ch[0].posX==moveX)
                            if(ch[0].posY==moveY)
                            busy = 1;} break;
                    }
                    else{
                        way = (rand() % 8);
                        cout<<way<<endl;
                        switch (way)
                        {
                            case 0: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                            case 1: {moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                            case 2: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY + 1;} break;
                            case 3: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1;} break;
                            case 4: {moveX = ch[i].posX + 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                            case 5: {moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                            case 6: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1; moveY = ch[i].posY - 1;} break;
                            case 7: {moveX = ch[i].posX - 1;} break;
                        }

                        for(int j=i-2; j>=0; j--){
                            if(moveX<0)
                            if(moveY<0)
                            if(ch[j].posX==moveX)                             //проверка наличия предыдущих чаров на клетке
                            if(ch[j].posY==moveY)
                                busy = 1;
                        }
                    }

                }while(busy == 1);

                playField[ch[i].posX] [ch[i].posY] = ch[i].area;    //восстановление значения территории

                ch[i].moveTo(moveX, moveY, i);
                //field.moveCh(moveX, moveY, i);
                ch[i].showPosition();
                ch[i].showId();
                cout<<endl<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    //field.moveToFile();

delete[] charId;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам переменные в области видимости целого файла? Почему у вас в классе поля с переменными не в private?

Comment: Вы сами решили так switch использовать или вам это кто-то показал? Это ужасно неверно. Всмысле то, где вы его используете впервые.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Область видимости переменных для их использования в объектах классов, поля с переменными не в привате для их изменения и использования в главной функции, а switch так использовать я сам решил.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch понял о чём вы. Изначально хотел добавить кейс с 0, но потом понял это не нужно, а т.к. всё работало, то забыл об этом.

Comment: переменные в общей области видимости никогда не должны размещаться, равно как и неинкапсулированные члены класса - тоже плохая идея, не для этого классы создавались. Для изменения членов класса используйте методы, а глобальных переменных НИКОГДА не делайте.

Comment: из-за этого switch совсем непонятно, что вы там имели ввиду. Впринципе ошибки нет, но это сильно усложняет чтение кода.

Comment: вы исправили, но вместо == указали присваивание.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не заметил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайное направление не реагирует на край карты, где направлений ограниченное количество. Поэтому абонент выходит за рамки отрицательных координат. Или в бесконечность.

Comment: Добавил костыль ограничивающий отрицательные значения, но проблема аномальных скачков никуда не делась.

Comment: Я тоже ограничил координаты и всё пашет. `if(moveX<0 or moveY<0 or moveX >= width or moveY >= length) busy = 1 ;`

Comment: действительно, большое спасибо.